# Laravel elixer versioning (cache buster) multiple servers

Tags: php, laravel, gulp, laravel-elixir

At the moment we have a new server environment with multiple servers, so the cache busting functionality of laravel elixer doesn't work if we download the repository and run gulp, as each server has a different version of the .js and .css file.

The problem is load balancing can send the user to either server per request.  Some browsers seem to be immune from the problem but for example I can't load the css or js properly using JMeter for load testing.

Is there a way to syncronize the build without adding the compiled files to the repository or FTPing everything?

We are trying to automate the deployment by running a script that pulls down the latest repo every time `productiosn` branch is updated.

Comment: It doesn't work? Or do you mean that you must keep committing redundant versions?

Comment: It works beautifully, but each server has a different cache busting file name

Comment: It's been a while since I've used laravel, so please remind me why this matters? Your source SASS should remain the same on each development machine and you're not committing the compiled css, so what does it matter if it's different? Or are you talking about some sort of load balancer issue with a clustered production environment so end users might have to get redundant copies of those resources depending on which node the load balancer tosses them to?

Comment: Updating question, but load balancer especially when running jmeter.

Comment: One simple way would be to write your own cache busting logic. Compile and before saving, pipe it through some hashing algorithm which ensures that the same contents will yield the same filename, yet the filename will differ when something is changed. Be sure to write to `manifest.json` as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that the only solution for this problem is to commit compiled assets files.

I found this solution strange at first, because we don't version `vendor` folder for example.

But at the end, I found that most of the front-end projects are always comitting a `dist` folder with compiled files.

So you would need to commit your `build` folder of your public path every time you make a modification to an asset file.

Of course, don't forget to make a `gulp --production` before pushing to minimize your files.

Comment: Thanks - I'll have a look on Monday and come back :)

Comment: I think you are close, but Dencker's suggestion should also be included in the answer :)